# What would a suitable pet project size for my resume be?

Tags: software-industry, resume

I'm planning to apply for a job that requires proficiency with a programming language I always liked but haven't worked with for a while. I studied the recent state of the language in question quite extensively, did lots of exercises, etc. However, it's going to be all talk and no action unless I demonstrate something real. I'm more than willing to invest some man-hours in a personal, non-commercial project.

The question is: How large should said project be in terms of man-hours of an industry-average experienced programmer? I understand full well that it's going to take much longer than that for a somewhat rusty guy like me, but I still need the order of magnitude. Dozens of man-hours? Hundreds? Thousands?

Or should it be measured in lines of code instead? All suggestions welcome.

Comment: why not say you use the language in your current job, if you're so sure you've actually mastered the requisite interview-knowledge?

Comment: More is better. Beyond that, I don't think we can really tell you what any given employer would be satisfied with. Some may be satisfied with as little as something you can pop out in an evening, if it's high-quality code. Others might see it negatively if there's nothing but that.

Comment: Never, ever use lines of code as a metric. That way lies madness.

Comment: @bharal: Perhaps the OP doesn't want to lie in an interview...

Comment: More is always better, I agree.  However, if we're talking about a job opportunity that's *currently being advertised* and you've done *nothing as of yet* then I think you should stick with something small.  You could also *start* something big and show it as a "work in progress."

Comment: @bharal: Getting past a recruiter is one thing. Keeping a job when they find out you lied in the interview; that's harder. And some people have a set of ethics that they like to live by.

Comment: @Steve-O I in fact have a reasonably ambitious personal project in development. Whether to put it on the resume or not is a good question, though: it includes some GUI ideas that I'd like to prevent from being borrowed until I release the thing. Made this mistake in the past and it cost me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Size doesn't matter.**

The important part is to *pick a project that interests you*. This could be a game, some kind of program to solve a real-world problem, or a more abstract application of some technology you always wanted to try.

You can join an open source project, or build something on your own, spend a weekend or an entire year. All that doesn't matter. It doesn't even have to be finished, as long as you have something to show/talk about.

If your skills are really rusty, you might want to start with some kind of coding exercise to get up to speed, but personally I wouldn't count that as a project, although that too depends on the challenge in question.

In my experience, hobby projects are a **great talking point in interviews**. They're an easy way for the employer to gauge the applicant's interest, coding style, priorities etc., and being excited about your project leaves a much better impression than being unwilling to talk about it because you found it boring.

I've never been asked how many lines of code I've written for any kind of project listed in my portfolio. Instead, the follow-up questions usually dig for details of features I implemented or how I solved problems I ran across.

You *may* be asked for a code sample, but recruiters are way too busy to slog through your entire project, so they'll probably ask for a much smaller sample. (If that happens, pick a self-contained aspect of your project that you're particularly proud of and can explain in detail, just in case they want to ask questions.)

Comment: A diversity of technologies/parts to the project helps. For example, an exercise tracker project would have database, models, controllers, views (forms + reports), and possibly an API. I once got a job because I showed off some iPhone apps I created, while the job had nothing to do with that technology. The interviewer wants to know what you are capable of.

Answer (score 3):

Select an application that people can relate to.

If you are targeting a specific industry then it could a business application.

Otherwise a personal product like a game, personal organization tool, or financial planner.  Pick an application that show the knowledge you want to show off.

You don't want it to be so big they are not going to review.

You can demonstrate a pretty good range of knowledge in 400 lines of code.

Comment: Not to argue but may I ask what the problem is with this answer?

Comment: i didn't dv, but i'd say it's because **nobody reviews homebrew code**. They don't have the time to. Hell, they won't even know if you got it from someone else. How will OP even demo it? How is it going to appear on their CV - "here is a 400 line code demo i did"?. Your average recruitment professional will not take the time to look at that.

Comment: @bharal Cool.  But if I felt that way I would VTC but not down vote answers.

Comment: Your answer gave me a curious idea: maybe I should github (the best of) my coding challenge solutions and put them on the resume. Still think they are good enough compared to what other guys post.

Answer (score 1):

If the answer to this question is in the hundreds of hours or even worse thousands of hours, that means that the current job posting you are looking at will be closed and filled long before you meet the threshold.

There is no way to know what will make them consider you as qualified. We do know that if they are using a system that scans your resume/application for key words and that language is a hard requirement and you don't include it,  then your application will not make it past the first screen.

As to if use in the past qualifies, it is hard to know. It could be good enough to have been proficient in the past. It might not be.

There is no harm in applying now. If you are ultimately going to be rejected the best place for you may be to make it to the interview or phone screen and to be told that if only your usage was more recent. Then that will give you an idea of what you need to do to make it farther into the process.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no one right answer.

You could do one big project, have multiple tiny little projects, or zero projects, and still win the job you want. So whatever you do, don't make the lack of a project become an excuse for you to not apply, or to wait too long to apply.

Apply for jobs right now. Applying for jobs, in part, is a numbers game.

And if you decide to create a project, which is a good idea, start with one as small as you can. If you start with one that's too ambitious, you may never finish it (or never finish it in a timely fashion).

Furthermore, I find that beginners often select the wrong type of projects to begin with because they're still just learning the strengths and weaknesses of their chosen platform. So a smaller project is easier to pivot away from if midway through it, you decide to do something different. A smaller project is also easier to publish and get immediate feedback on. And having a shorter feedback loop, I find, can also be very motivating.

> I studied the recent state of the language in question quite
>   extensively, did lots of exercises, etc.

Are you applying for a junior position? "did lots of exercises" is very vague to me.

For all I know, you may already be ready for a junior position.

If you're afraid of rejection, I'd suggest that you do a number of mock interviews with other job-hunters through this site: http://pramp.com

Everyone using that site is at a different level, and after a number of those mock interviews, you'll get a feel for how it feels to be an interviewer who interviews candidates of very different levels.

Comment: 'Are you applying for a junior position? "did lots of exercises" is very vague to me.' - To be more specific, I solved a few dozen HackerRank and Codility challenges labeled 'hard' with maximum scores. On my own, without googling the answers. :) Yes, I'm willing to accept a job title downgrade here.

Comment: @sigil, You don't need a project. I'm serious. You should still start one of course. But you should easily get a job if you apply to enough positions.

Answer (score 0):

Find a personal itch and solve it in a small way.  This is the only way that you actually gets the full benefit of doing this.

A small library helping you to do something can be perfect.  The amount of actual code can be rather little but it solves a problem and if you use it you will evolve it over time and provide documentation etc.  You may use https://github.com/statsbiblioteket/streamtuples as inspiration.

Another approach is to do documentation projects.  You have an technology which is hard to use for some reason, and you create a small project which as clearly as you can explains how to use it with actual code.  I did this with Dagger 2.  https://github.com/ravn/dagger2-hello-world

The important thing is that you treat it as real code and not just some display piece never to be looked at again.  This will show very quickly.